# Ctrl+= does not open a box

Tags: keyboard, input

In the `guide/WolframAlphaIntegration` documentation it says that

<kbd>=</kbd> : use free-form linguistics to generate Wolfram Language output

<kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>: generate full Wolfram|Alpha output

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> : enters free-form linguistics

But for me (*Mathematica* 10.0.2) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> does not open a box as it should (see [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/real-world-entities/))

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 5):

The keyboard shortcut *might* be different on your computer if you use a non-English keyboard layout.  Or at least it's worth checking this.

Go to the Insert menu and look for "Inline free-form input".  It's the fourth entry in the menu.  The keyboard shortcut will be shown next to it.

[image]

Comment: This should really be more clear in the documentation, I recall that Estonian keyboards had huge problems with most built-in shortcuts in Mma.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Using the menu, everything is fine !

Comment: @FrançoisHurter So did you find the correct shortcut?  What was it?  And what keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: Ah no, the shortcut does not work ! Only the "menu" approach...

Comment: What is strange is that the menu shows Ctrl+= but it does not work. I have a Swiss french keyboard.

Comment: @FrançoisHurter So what you tried was Shift-Control-0?  Also try just Control-0 and try Control-^ (if ^ is the key just left of backspace).  It probably won't work but it's maybe worth a atry.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is typical for all keyboard layouts where `=` is typed in by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>, for example, as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> on a German keyboard.

On such a keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> is typed in using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. However, under Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> by default is the keyboard shortcut used to switch between input languages. The following screen snipped shows how to deactivate this default behavior and therefore get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to insert the *Inline Free-form Input*.
[image: ScreenSnipped]